# use String.split method in Java and put the tokens into an array

Tags: java, string, split

I don't understand why my code below doesn't work. I am trying to read a text file using buffered reader and split the first line, and then put each word into an array.

The System.out.println prints out all array items in the input text, instead of the first word. I couldn't figure out why. Many thanks for your help in advance!

```
String [] words = line.split(" "); 
System.out.println(words[0]);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work?

Comment: My input file only contains 3 words, but when I tried to print out words [0], [1] and[100], they all give me the same result, which is the all three words in the input file. It seems that the words have not been put into the array.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a few issues in your code, there is a handy method in [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) and then something like this ...

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
String line = input.readLine(); // Java variable names should be lower case.
                                // Constants are ALL CAPS. Please follow conventions.  
String [] words = line.split(" "); // words, not Words - and line (not firstLine). 
System.out.println("Line : " + Arrays.toString(words)); //  Arrays.toString(words)
                      // not words[100]... which would be the 101st word (which
                      // is a very long line).
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I have changed the names of the variables.The reason why I put in words[100] was because my input file only had three words (i.e. a text file with words: blue red yellow). But it still printed out all three. I tried words[0] and [1], and it gave me the same result. It seems that the words haven't been put into the array? Many thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure there's a space, and not some other character (like a tab), between each word?